# OpenLayers ol.proj.get returns null after adding projection definition to Proj4

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

I just stumbled upon the following problem :

OpenLayers is unable to retrieve a projection definition even though it has been previously registered with Proj4JS. Code below :

```
   import proj4 from 'proj4/dist/proj4'; // Proj4JS version 2.4.4

   import proj from 'ol/proj'; // OpenLayers version 4.6.5

   proj4.defs('EPSG:2154', '+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');

   console.log(proj.get('EPSG:2154')); // displays null
```

I can not figure out anything but a version mismatch as reported in [OpenLayers 3 not recognising proj4 custom projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230472/openlayers-3-not-recognising-proj4-custom-projection/230619)

Answer (score 4):

Just found the answer on [OpenLayers Github](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/4875)

The reason is the 'import' syntax used to bring OL and Proj4JS into scope.  With this syntax, one has to make sure OL is aware of Proj4JS by using the ol.proj.setProj4 function.

Correct code is :

```
import proj4 from 'proj4/dist/proj4';
import proj from 'ol/proj';

proj.setProj4(proj4);    // <=== Add this line

proj4.defs('EPSG:2154', '....whathever....');
var proj2154 = proj.get('EPSG:2154'); // not null now
```

Answer (score 4):

Previous answer is right. 
I want only note that in Openlayers 5 this is changed. 
As noted at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj_Projection-Projection.html, in similar cases you must use

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:2154', '+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');

ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); // register proj4 in openlayer after a proj4.defs
```